# jQuery to alter the MYSQL tables column name dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drupal-7

I have a table in my page and iam using mysql. The problem is that i wanted to add a new field dynamically to it. The option adds the column name and then the values. After adding the column fields then it should ask for the added column for the input data.
Iam thinking of altering the column names after getting the column  names from the user.
Is it possible.
which may be the efficient way to approach this problem.

For clarity...the problem is

I have 3 columns ( in my MYSQL  table total of 6 )say COL1, COL2, COL3.
When i ask for input its is like this:

```
 COL1:  ___________________
 COL2:  ___________________
 COL3:  ___________________
 Do you want more fields : y/N
```

If YES, then i want to add COL4, COL5,COL6 for them with a **max of 3**. ( i added a 6 columns in the table with the 3 columns with NULL values for the extra usage ) 
ALSO, i have to allow user to decide the COLUMN Name. In more clear way, if "y" is selected, then a popup with two fields - one for the Column name and its respective data

```
_________________   :  ________________
```

. After that the column name should be able to show directly and ask just for the data.

```
    COL1:  ___________________
    COL2:  ___________________
    COL3:  ___________________
   theCOLUMNNAME  : ___________________
   Do you want more fields : y/N
```

### EDIT

I have used jQuery to add the field entries dynamically like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_button', function(){
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>  <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="images/remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
    }
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
});

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a new name or id for the input you must to use 
**prompt**

```
var newid = prompt("Set the new ID");
```

that allows you to enter a value and assign the value in a var and then set in the input.

Ok, let's do this!

First: replace the id:

```
var id = "input" + $(this).attr("id").replace("field","");
```

Second: ask the new ID, name or value

```
id = prompt("Set the new ID");
```

Third: assign the id and value for label

```
var label = $("<label for=\"" + id + "\">" + id + "</label>");
```

Fourth: assign the id, name or value to the input

```
input = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\"+ value=\"" + id + "\" />");
```

Here the code. I used this example: https://jsfiddle.net/qBURS/2/ and I modified the JS

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
    <legend>Build your own form!</legend>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Preview form" class="add" id="preview" />
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" />");
    var fType = $("<select class=\"fieldtype\"><option value=\"checkbox\">Checked</option><option value=\"textbox\">Text</option><option value=\"textarea\">Paragraph</option></select>");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(fType);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
});
$("#preview").click(function() {
    $("#yourform").remove();
    var fieldSet = $("<fieldset id=\"yourform\"><legend>Your Form</legend></fieldset>");
    $("#buildyourform div").each(function() {
        var id = "input" + $(this).attr("id").replace("field","");

        id = prompt("Set the new ID");

        var label = $("<label for=\"" + id + "\">" + id + "</label>");
        var input;
        switch ($(this).find("select.fieldtype").first().val()) {
            case "checkbox":
                input = $("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" />");
                break;
            case "textbox":
                input = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\"+ value=\"" + id + "\" />");
                break;
            case "textarea":
                input = $("<textarea id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" ></textarea>");
                break;    
        }
        fieldSet.append(label);
        fieldSet.append(input);

    });
    $("body").append(fieldSet);
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: can u tell how this can be done dynamically in the MYSQL table also. like adding the new fields to the MYSQL table dynamically.

Comment: You're welcome; If you need on mysql you could use insert and delete, I don't know if I undertand your question